# How to expire/dispose Notifications in Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, notifications

I enabled notifications in my app and its working fine but how can I expire an old notification if a new one arrives or expire it after a certain duration?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The "flutter_local_notifications" plugin has a method to dismiss notifications. However, there is currently no method to get a list of the present notifications. You need to track them on your own (e.g. some persistent storage like SharedPreferences).

Answer (score 0):

#### Retrieving pending notification requests :

```
final List<PendingNotificationRequest> pendingNotificationRequests =
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.pendingNotificationRequests();
```

###### cancel the notification with id value of zero

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancel(0);
```

###### Cancelling/deleting all notifications

```
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
```

---

you can achieve this with the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications).